# Dividir uma String dinamicamente baseado no tamanho da tela

Tags: java, android, string, algoritmo

Estou trabalhando em um app de android e em certo momento recebo uma String de um web-service que é bem grande, e o cliente quer que essa *String*
(que será mostrada em um *EditText*) seja dividida em múltiplas partes, formando tipo uma paginação (pensei em usar um *ViewPager* para fazer essa navegação).

Bem, mas o problema é que não sei como eu posso Fazer essa "quebra da string" me baseando no tamanho da tela, sem que haja scroll , nem que uma palavra seja cortada e usando o máximo da tela possível. Sem contar que o tamanho da fonte vai ser  customizável também, podendo o usuário aumentar/diminuir a fonte a qualquer momento.
E tudo esse tratamento tem que ser feito dinamicamente, porque essa String retornada nunca é a mesma.

Alguém tem alguma sugestão?!

Comment: Essa é uma ótima pergunta

Answer (score 3):

Bem, em linhas gerais, você pode fazer o seguinte (o processo abaixo deve ser repetido toda vez que a string mudar, ou que a largura ou altura do mudarem, ou que o tamanho da fonte mudar):

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
//defina sua fonte aqui, caso deseje
paint.setTextSize(<TAMANHO DA FONTE EM PIXELS>);

StaticLayout layout = new StaticLayout(<SUA STRING>, paint, <LARGURA DISPONÍVEL>, Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 1, 0, false);

int lineCount = layout.getLineCount();
String lines[] = new String[lineCount];
for (int i = 0; i < lineCount; i++)
    lines[i] = <SUA STRING>.substring(layout.getLineStart(i), layout.getLineEnd(i));
```

Com isso o array `lines` irá conter sua string original divida em linhas, sem que haja quebra de palavras (sempre que possível).

A partir daí, você pode desenhar as linhas na tela manualmente utilizando o `Canvas` fornecido nos métodos `onDraw` da classe `View`, ou você pode concatenar uma quantidade qualquer dessas linhas, e atribuir esse resultado a um `TextView`.

Para saber quantas linhas cabem em uma determinada altura, basta utilizar a altura da linha para aquela fonte (*box*):

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
//defina sua fonte aqui, caso deseje
paint.setTextSize(<TAMANHO DA FONTE EM PIXELS>);

Paint.FontMetrics fm = paint.getFontMetrics();
int lineHeight = (int)(fm.descent - fm.ascent + 0.5f);

int linesPerView = <ALTURA DA VIEW> / lineHeight;
```

Caso queira mais informações, você pode ver um exemplo completo disso [aqui, em um projeto meu no GitHub](https://github.com/carlosrafaelgn/FPlayAndroid/blob/master/src/br/com/carlosrafaelgn/fplay/ui/RadioStationView.java).

Answer (score 0):

Pode obter o **width** da string e tabalhar em cima disto.

```
Paint mPaint = new Paint();
mPaint.setTextSize(/*put here ur size*/);
mPaint.setTypeface(/* put here ur font type */);
Rect bounds = new Rect();
mPaint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), bounds);
bounds.width();
```

Fonte: [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7329004/android-and-calculating-the-size-of-a-one-line-string-in-a-given-font-and-font-s)